# Where can I find military records for soldiers in Merrill's Marauders?

Tags: world-war-two, war, world

My uncle fought with [Merrill's Marauders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merrill%27s_Marauders). Can I get more information on his military awards?

Comment: Where have you looked? Have you tried the [National Personnel Records Center](https://www.archives.gov/personnel-records-center)?

Comment: There is that, but there may also be a little disappointment so one might be prepared for same https://www.archives.gov/personnel-records-center/fire-1973

Comment: This might be a good place to start, but it is not digitized, so you'd have to go there or hire a researcher.  https://catalog.archives.gov/id/1187339.  And for just a general history, there's this https://history.army.mil/books/wwii/marauders/marauders-fw.htm